# Linker can't find -lgcc [CMU Malloc Lab]

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, linker, system

I'm trying to `make` the following `makefile` code

```
#
# Students' Makefile for the Malloc Lab
#
TEAM = bovik
VERSION = 1
HANDINDIR = /afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15213-f01/malloclab/handin

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2 -m32

OBJS = mdriver.o mm.o memlib.o fsecs.o fcyc.o clock.o ftimer.o

mdriver: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o mdriver $(OBJS)

mdriver.o: mdriver.c fsecs.h fcyc.h clock.h memlib.h config.h mm.h
memlib.o: memlib.c memlib.h
mm.o: mm.c mm.h memlib.h
fsecs.o: fsecs.c fsecs.h config.h
fcyc.o: fcyc.c fcyc.h
ftimer.o: ftimer.c ftimer.h config.h
clock.o: clock.c clock.h

handin:
    cp mm.c $(HANDINDIR)/$(TEAM)-$(VERSION)-mm.c

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o mdriver
```

but get an error message

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -m32 -o mdriver mdriver.o mm.o memlib.o fsecs.o fcyc.o clock.o ftimer.o
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'mdriver' failed
make: *** [mdriver] Error 1
```

Things that I have tried include:

1. Install  gcc-multilib, libc6-i386, libc6-dev-i386 lib32gcc1, lib32stdc++6,libc6-dev-i386
2. export  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu

In my system, there is no `libgcc.so` file but `libgcc_s.so` and `libgcc_s.so.1`. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Perhaps the gcc-multilib doesn't match the installed version of gcc. Try installing gcc-7-multilib.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Bingo. It works. Thank you so much.